# Axios Promise Resolution / Pending Promise

Tags: javascript, axios, es6-promise

I have the following issue, regarding promise resolution in JS.

Frontend code:

```
const test = () => {
    try {
      let response = axios.post("http://localhost:5000/auth/test").then(
        (res) => {
          console.log("received")
          console.log(res)
      });
      console.log(response);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
```

Backend python code:

```
@auth.route("/test", methods=["POST"])
def test():
    import time
    time.sleep(0.5)
    return jsonify("Test Request"), 200
```

In my console it says `*Promise {<pending>}*` but never "received". Why is that? How can I await the response of the backend?

Comment: Did you test your backend route itself? Does it work with curl? Btw, can you try async/await?

Comment: Hi, yes I also now added "GET" as a method:
❯ curl -X GET "http://localhost:5000/auth/test" returns {"msg":"Test Request"}

Comment: ok. try to use axios.get().then().catch(); (without try catch). or try to use async/await.

Comment: This also does not work it seems :(
```
  const test = async () => {

    await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/auth/test").then(
        (res) => {
          console.log("received")
          console.log(res)
      }).catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
    });
  };
```

Comment: Http methods should be `POST` not `GET`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code wouldn't work, Because `try/carch` block only catch errors from awaited promise.

Because `await` keyword suspense promise and return value from it.

This is the same reason you got `Promise {<pending>}` message.

```js
async function test() {
  try {
    let response = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/auth/test");
    console.log(response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I had this before like but I do not get any log or message anymore using this version. IDK, maybe I am doing something wrong at a different place in React

Comment: I tested this with a fresh new react project. And the above works.